# how to translate the answer entered by the user in arabic to english

Tags: python, google-translate

I want to translate the answer entered by the user in Arabic to English and then train it in the models but its not working please if anyone can help me!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, jsonify      
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer 
import pickle
import numpy as np
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
app = Flask(__name__)`

# Load the TF-IDF vocabulary specific to the category

with open(r"toxic_vect.pkl", "rb") as f:
   tox = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"severe_toxic_vect.pkl", "rb") as f:
   sev = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"obscene_vect.pkl", "rb") as f:
   obs = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"insult_vect.pkl", "rb") as f:
   ins = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"threat_vect.pkl", "rb") as f:
   thr = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"identity_hate_vect.pkl", "rb") as f:
   ide = pickle.load(f)`

# Load the pickled RDF models

with open(r"toxic_model.pkl", "rb") as f:
   tox_model = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"severe_toxic_model.pkl", "rb") as f:
   sev_model = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"obscene_model.pkl", "rb") as f:
   obs_model  = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"insult_model.pkl", "rb") as f:
   ins_model  = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"threat_model.pkl", "rb") as f:
   thr_model  = pickle.load(f)

with open(r"identity_hate_model.pkl", "rb") as f:
   ide_model  = pickle.load(f)`

# Render the HTML file for the home page

@app.route("/")
def home():
   return render_template('index_toxic.html')

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():

   # Take a string input from user
   data = request.form['text']

   #translate data to english
   translator = Translator()
   result = translator.translate(data)
   data = result.text
   data = [data]

   vect = tox.transform(data)
   pred_tox = tox_model.predict_proba(vect)[:,1]

   vect = sev.transform(data)
   pred_sev = sev_model.predict_proba(vect)[:,1]

   vect = obs.transform(data)
   pred_obs = obs_model.predict_proba(vect)[:,1]

   vect = thr.transform(data)
   pred_thr = thr_model.predict_proba(vect)[:,1]

   vect = ins.transform(data)
   pred_ins = ins_model.predict_proba(vect)[:,1]

   vect = ide.transform(data)
   pred_ide = ide_model.predict_proba(vect)[:,1]

   out_tox = round(pred_tox[0], 2)
   out_sev = round(pred_sev[0], 2)
   out_obs = round(pred_obs[0], 2)
   out_ins = round(pred_ins[0], 2)
   out_thr = round(pred_thr[0], 2)
   out_ide = round(pred_ide[0], 2)

   print(out_tox)

   return render_template('index_toxic.html', 
                           pred_tox='Prob (Toxic): {}'.format(out_tox),
                           pred_sev='Prob (Severe Toxic): {}'.format(out_sev), 
                           pred_obs='Prob (Obscene): {}'.format(out_obs),
                           pred_ins='Prob (Insult): {}'.format(out_ins),
                           pred_thr='Prob (Threat): {}'.format(out_thr),
                           pred_ide='Prob (Identity Hate): {}'.format(out_ide)                        
                         )
 
# Server reloads itself if code changes so no need to keep restarting:

app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the errors I get in html page:

```
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\elidr\Desktop\PFE - Copie\toxic_comments_classifier-master\toxic_comments_classifier-master\Flask app for toxic comments\toxic_app.py", line 66, in predict
   vect = tox.transform(data)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1898, in transform
    X = super().transform(raw_documents)
File "C:\Users\elidr\.conda\envs\toxic\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1264, in transform
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received
```

when you call

```
vect = tox.transform(data)
```

in your code.

From [sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1227), we learn that:

```
raw_documents : iterable
            An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects
```

So turn `data` from a string object into an iterable that yields strings:

```
def raw_documents(data):
    for line in data.splitlines():
        assert isinstance(line, str)
        yield line
```

and use it like this:

```
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate(data)
data = result.text
vect = tox.transform(raw_documents(data))
```